# WSO2 ESB - writing files out of base64

Tags: base64, wso2, esb, mediator

I have a proxy which accepts XML files with Base64 encoded files in it. For example the XML looks like:

```
<message>
  <content>Hello World</content>
  <attachements>
     <attachement>*Base64 code here*</attachement>
     <attachement>*Base64 code here*</attachement>
     <attachement>*Base64 code here*</attachement>
  </attachements>
</message>
```

My Problem:
I like to save the decoded files from the message into a folder of the filesystem of the server running the ESB. But how can I do this? If I encode a simple text like "Hello World" with Base64 I can decode it with an Script Mediator and Javascript, but how can I write a file to the filesystem? Do I have to write my own Mediator or is there another solution I don't know?

Would be nice if you could help me :)
I'm using the WSO2 ESB for my bachelor thesis. So I'm not a professional yet :)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options,

1. If file sizes are small, iterate through `<attachments>` and for each attachment, decode using the script mediator and write to a file with syntax like,

   ```
   <property name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName"
             expression="expression-to-compute-file-name"
             scope="transport"/>
   <property action="set" name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
   <send>
       <endpoint>
           <address uri="vfs:file:///home/user/test/out"/>
       </endpoint>
   </send>
   ```
2. If the files are large then it's more efficient to write your own class mediator

Answer (score 0):

Send the files to an local filesystem . Use [VFS proxy](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15471427)