# WSO2 ESB: How to write a file from Base64 with VFS?

Tags: wso2-esb

I have pretty much the same issue as this person:
[WSO2 ESB - writing files out of base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961413/wso2-esb-writing-files-out-of-base64)

However, in the answer to that question there was no mention of how to decode the Base64 string in JavaScript and attach it to the payload. That's what I'm interested in.

Thanks in advance,

Strainy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with a slightly different approach. I created a utility proxy service to re-download the file and then push it into the file system.

#### utilty_createFile Proxy Service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="utility_createFile"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="utility_createFile_IN" outSequence="utility_createFile_OUT"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

#### utility_createFile_IN Sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="utility_createFile_IN" onError="fault" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
    <property expression="//createFile/download_folder"
        name="uri.var.download_folder" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="//createFile/url" name="uri.var.download_url" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var download_url = mc.getProperty('uri.var.download_url');
download_url = decodeURIComponent(download_url);
mc.setProperty('uri.var.download_url', download_url);]]></script>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="{uri.var.download_url}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

#### utility_createFile_OUT Sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="utility_createFile_IN" onError="fault" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
    <property expression="//createFile/download_folder"
        name="uri.var.download_folder" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="//createFile/url" name="uri.var.download_url" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var download_url = mc.getProperty('uri.var.download_url');
download_url = decodeURIComponent(download_url);
mc.setProperty('uri.var.download_url', download_url);]]></script>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="GET" uri-template="{uri.var.download_url}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

Comment: The code you shared in the OUT sequence is the code of the IN sequence. Could you update your anwser?