# wso2 esb write base64 pdf content to file

Tags: pdf, wso2, base64, esb, wso2-esb

Same issue as [WSO2 ESB - writing files out of base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961413/wso2-esb-writing-files-out-of-base64) and [WSO2 ESB: How to write a file from Base64 with VFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108253/wso2-esb-how-to-write-a-file-from-base64-with-vfs)

What's the solution to Base64 decode and create the payload to send to file?

As an alternative used the file connector 2. The pdf file is created but adobe reader shows an empty page.

operating: wso2 esb 4.8.1

Comment: Solution: Used a javascript with Base64.decode and charset ISO-8859-1, and write to fie with the fileconnector with encoding ISO-8859-1